# Example of a section $s$ of a presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ which is not determined by $\{ s_x \}_{x}$.

Tags: sheaf-theory

One of the advantages of working with a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ instead of a presheaf is that every section $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ is determined by the family of its germs $\{ s_x \}_{x \in U}$. I know this may fail for a presheaf in general, since you don't have the gluing axiom. Can anyone show me an example of this phenomenon?

(Maybe I want my base space $X$ to satisfy some separation axiom, to avoid trivial examples; of course trivial examples are welcome too.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the sheaf $\mathcal C$ of real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ and its subpresheaf $\mathcal C_b$ of bounded functions,  defined by the requirement that on an open subset $U\subset \mathbb R$ the sections of $\mathcal C_b(U)$ consist in  the *bounded* continuous functions $U\to \mathbb R$.
The quotient presheaf $\mathcal F$ defined by $U\mapsto \mathcal F(U)=\mathcal C(U)/\mathcal C_b(U) $ is an example of the type of presheaf that you want.
Indeed all $\mathcal F_x \;(x\in \mathbb R)$ are zero because any continuous function defined on a neighbourhood of  $x$ is  bounded in a suitable  smaller neighborhood of $x$.
However  any global continuous unbounded function $f\in \mathcal C (\mathbb R) $ (like $x$ or $e^x$) is an example of a non- zero class in $\mathcal F(\mathbb R)$: $$0\neq \bar f\in \mathcal F(\mathbb R)=\mathcal C(\mathbb R)/\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R) \;\text {although all } (\bar f)_x=0_x\in \mathcal F_x=\{0_x\}$$

Comment: Is the sheafification of this going to be $\mathcal{F}(U)=\{ 0 \}$ as well?

Comment: Dear Lor, yes ! This follows from two general facts which are worth remembering: 1) A presheaf and its sheafification have the exact same stalks.  2) A sheaf $\mathcal F$ all of whose stalks $\mathcal F_x$ are zero must be the zero sheaf,  that is all  its $\mathcal F (U)$ 's are zero.

Answer (score 7):

Georges Elencwajg has given a correct example, but here's a simpler one that might also be helpful.  Let $X$ be a discrete space with just two points $p$ and $q$.  Define a presheaf $F$ by letting $F(\{p,q\})=\{0,1\}$ while $F(\{p\})=F(\{q\})=F(\varnothing)=\{0\}$; the restriction maps are the only possible ones.  Then both of the stalks are singletons, so the two gobal sections have the same stalk at each point.

Comment: Since I'm just a beginner in sheaf theory I really appreciate this simple example. The sheafification of this presheaf would be the sheaf $\mathcal{F}(U)=\{ 0 \}$, am I right? which is, in a sense, smaller.

Comment: Yes, you are right: see point 2) in my comment to my question.